# How to let a SmartWatch vibrate from an HTML5 page without intervention

Tags: android-vibration

As I have developed a solution for people with Alzheimer’s, Dementia and for instance an Autisme Spectrum Disorder, that normally is shown on tablets (see www.dontforgetit.eu), I have made also an Android APP to be installed on a SmartWatch.

This app is developed with Android Studio and has an HTML5 background (as for the tablets).

What I do is I start with a page that needs to be tapped. It vibrates and that goes to the actual HTML5 page showing upcoming appointments and other obligations. The maximum ages shown is three (a clock, the actual event and the upcoming event). The upcoming event is only shown 5 minutes before the actual event terminates. Three minutes before the actual event stops and the upcoming events starts, the SmartWatch needs to vibrate.

For that reason I start with the earlier mentioned start page. However I get the following message "Blocked call to navigator.vibrate because user hasn't tapped on the frame or any embedded frame yet: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5644273861001216.” and the Watch doesn’t vibrate.

How do I solve this problem, preventing the disabled person to continue tapping the Watch?

Comment: PLease add a minimal code example to illustrate your issue.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question.
Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages and stack traces.